# Does creating DynamoDB GSI on existing table, indexes old records?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB table with few thousand records. As per my business need, I want to create a GSI(Global Secondary Index) on one of the field. I am not sure if my existing records will be indexed or not. Does it indexes existing data or only new incoming data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does. You can also monitor the progress of indexing process in AWS Cloudwatch where DynamoDB publishes the [`OnlineIndexPercentageProgress`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/dynamo-metricscollected.html)  metric for the GSI being created.

You can also speed up the indexing process by tuning the read-capacity for the base table for the duration of indexing.